# football data problem: how to filter an input to avoid duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, join, input, indexing

very new to python - I'm using an input to find similar players to the input (player) I type. The problem with this is I have 2 seasons of data & putting a name in the input means I get a duplicate error message. how do I solve this?

```
player_comparison = str(input('Enter the player name you want to replace: '))
season_player = str(input('Enter the season: '))

column = str(player_comparison)
season_column = str(season_player)

sim_player_top7 = sim_matrix[column].reset_index().sort_values(by=column,ascending=False)
sim_player_top7 = pd.merge(sim_player_top7, df5[['name', 'clusters', 'season']],
on=['name'],how='outer').rename(columns={column: column + " - Eucilidian Similarity %", "name":"Player name", "season":"Season"}).head(30)

season_filter = column.join(df5)
sim_player_top7 = sim_player_top7[sim_player_top7['Player name']!=column]

sim_player_top7 = season_filter["season"]==season_column
sim_player_top7
```

Above is the code that gives the result in a table, **note that the above code does work when the player isn't a duplicate value.**

What I was aiming for was to join the 1st input & the dataframe to get the season of the player entered in the 1st input (*season_filter*). I then match the season in the join with the 2nd input where I enter the season (if that makes any sense...)

[sample dataset is here as requested](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av7gOXm5R0eRgVlFGY0jigGWJlUA?e=C58DBd)

Comment: Please add some sample data, and I presume you're using Pandas. If so, you should state that and add a `pandas` tag. It would also be helpful to include a minimal reproducible example in your question

Comment: @badhushamuhammed a sample dataset has been added so you understand what I mean. It will be hard to add a reproducible example as the code goes on for a while cause I'm using KMeans clustering. Can upload full code if needed